# xrandr shows DP-1 as connected instead HDMI-1

Tags: 18.04, hdmi, xrandr

I have a display device connected to the computer through HDMI cable. The monitor generally works, but fails after hibernating ("no signal"). Why `xrandr` show DP-1 as connected despite the fact that I'm using HDMI port?

```
$ xrandr -display :0.0 -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 217mm x 136mm
   1280x800      59.81 +
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

$ DISPLAY=:0 xrandr --prop
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 217mm x 136mm
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff004c2dff0b01000000
        27180103806639780a0adf9a59529425
        204b53bfee0081c00101010101010101
        0101010101019e20009051201f304880
        3600d9880000001c011d007251d01e20
        6e285500d9880000001e000000fd0018
        4b1a5111000a202020202020000000fc
        0053796e634d61737465720a20200125
        020326f14b841303120514101f202122
        2309070783010000e2000fe305030166
        030c00100080023a801871382d40582c
        4500d9880000001e023a80d072382d40
        102c4580d9880000001e011d8018711c
        1620582c2500d9880000009e011d80d0
        721c1620102c2580d9880000009e0000
        0000000000000000000000000000001a
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
   1280x800      59.81 +
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Same problem here... Mine shows DP-1 but it's hdmi But it's weird, I can display 1920x1080p but the default 2560x1600 gives no signal no matter what